# cannot route local traffic through openvpn on linux

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have set up an openvpn server on my remote machine. It works, I can connect with both android client and linux (opensuse) client.
the problem is that on android I can access the remote local resources (I'm interesed in reaching my router) but I cannot on my dekstop. 
Running openvpn in a terminal using the autogenerated config file clearly shows:

```
/bin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1
/bin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1
/bin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.8.0.1
```

that should mean that all the traffic from client machine is routed through vpn gateway, but the remote resources are still unreachable.
The android client generated configuration in openvpn client says

```
route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 vpn_gateway
no bind
```

and it works perfectly.

This is ip tables on my linux client look like

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2 
<server-public-ip> via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp3s0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.60 metric 600
```

and on my server

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.91 metric 202 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1  
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.91 metric   202
```

What else can I try?

Comment: What do the routing tables look like on both devices after starting the VPN?

Comment: adding it to the question

Comment: By chance, is the remote address you are trying to connect to in 192.168.1.0/24?

Comment: I get anything on 192.168.1.0/24 and the problem is that I can still access my local netowork resources

Comment: It is getting strange because connecting with the same profile in a ubuntu virtual machine works as I expect it to

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that first reply there

Comment: I still can access the local resources, this means that local addresses are not being routed I guess. even after activating the vpn via command line I cannot see 0.0.0.0/0 vpn_gateway in my ip routes, but only 0.0.0.0/1

Comment: Local addresses, as in 192.168.0.1/24 will always be reachable since the route is more specific than the ones created by the VPN (/24 vs /1). This is necessary because traffic headed to the VPN server still needs to go out your original default route of 192.168.1.1. The VPN creates two routes, 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 to cover the rest of the traffic. I'm wondering what the remote router's IP address is, as that would help.

Comment: the remote router ip address in the remote network is 192.168.1.1 and the local router is 192.168.1.254 . what really drives me crazy is that on other devices or installation of the same system it works, I cannot reach 192.168.1.254 but I can reach 192.168.1.1 when connected to the vpn while on the actual machine is the oposite

Comment: Might help to use a different subnet for one of the networks so there aren't any conflicts.

Comment: I think I traced the issue: there's an extra line in ip route that routes the local traffic, I don't know how to remove it

Comment: As explained above, that line is necessary to reach your default gateway. You need to change the subnets so there is no conflict

Comment: it's not the defualt gateway one, is another one. I have, by default default via:  192.168.1.254 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.60 metric 600